# Cohomology and p-adic L-functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, l-functions

The definitions of $p$-adic $L$-functions I know all are given by interpolating the values of "usual" $L$-functions at the negative integers. If I want to define the $p$-adic $L$-function of a scheme (say smooth, proper over a number field), the naive thing to do would be to study the action of Frobenius on the cohomology of the scheme and look at the associated Euler product. Since this is not the definition taken in the literature, this must be the wrong idea, but it's not clear to me why.

Is there any cohomological interpretation of "the" $p$-adic $L$-function a scheme?

Comment: Convergence would be a serious problem. Daniel Delbourgo managed to write it as a sort of a [Dirichlet series](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/806C43C715D5958AF7A17E75E9D5D3E9/S1446788700015846a.pdf/dirichlet_series_expansion_for_the_padic_zetafunction.pdf).

Comment: The same author also wrote ["The convergence of Euler products over p-adic number fields"](https://www-cambridge-org.nottingham.idm.oclc.org/core/journals/proceedings-of-the-edinburgh-mathematical-society/article/convergence-of-euler-products-over-padic-number-fields/7B09E64657CEAD8EBC8CF218175B4ACD) which may answer this better.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich That link requires a Nottingham login to access

Comment: Aye. Sorry! [This doi](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0013091507000636) is "The convergence of Euler products over p-adic number fields" (MR2546633 on mathscinet. and [this link](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/806C43C715D5958AF7A17E75E9D5D3E9/S1446788700015846a.pdf/dirichlet_series_expansion_for_the_padic_zetafunction.pdf) is "A Dirichlet series expansion for the p-adic zeta-function" (MR2267793). I don't have a link without a paywall, sorry.